# The functional equation and differentiability

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, at the same time satisfying the following two conditions:
>
> a) $f (x + yf (x)) = f (x) f (y)$
>
> b) the function $f$ can be represented in the form $f (x) = (\varphi (x)) ^ 2, x \in \mathbb R,$ where the function $f$ has a finite derivative at $x = 0.$ (not infinite)

I have no clue how to start. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'finite derivative'? Non zero, not infinite?

Comment: @ copper.hat:  not infinite

Comment: $f(0)=f(0)^2$ $f(0)=0$

Comment: Is $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ a solution? Doesn't solve the problem, though.

Comment: @kmitov also $f(0)=1$ is possible

Comment: @ MXYMXY: $f(х)=\max \left\{cx+1, 0\right\}$

Comment: Related: [Solving the Functional Equation $ f \big( x + y f ( x ) \big) = f ( x ) f ( y ) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2300513/229831).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach.

Plug in $y=0$ to get
$$
f(x) = f(x) f(0),
$$
so either $f(x) \equiv 0$ or $f(0)=1$.

Now note that
$$
f(x+yf(x)) = f(y+xf(y))
$$
and assuming $f$ is 1-to-1, we have
$$
x + yf(x) = y + xf(y)\\
x(1-f(y)) = y(1-f(x))\\
\frac{x}{1-f(x)} = \frac{y}{1-f(y)}
$$
for arbitrary $x,y$, and that means both LHS and RHS and constant, say $c$.Then you have
$$
c = \frac{x}{1-f(x)} \\
f(x) = 1 - x/c
$$

**UPDATE**
If $f$ is not 1-1, $f(x) \equiv 1$ is a solution, but not sure if there are others...

Comment: Why $$f(x+yf(x)) = f(y+xf(y)) \Rightarrow x + yf(x) = y + xf(y)$$?

Comment: @Roman83 if you assume $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$. Notice the result satisfies this property as well as that $f(0)=1$...